# Install Debian packages to run Airflow DAG

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, airflow, bag, rosbag

I'm running an Airflow DAG one of the operators is a BashOperator and relies on rosbag package in order to run. I installed airflow and rosbag in a VM in GCP, everything is working fine but when I trigger the DAG it keeps saying rosbag: command not found any idea how to solve it?

I've followed all the instructions in http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu

Comment: I am not sure if it will work, but have you tried to source the ROS environment before invoking the actual `rosbag` command in your `bashoperator` `command`? `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash && rosbag`

Comment: You are welcome!! That is great @Dudes!! I am happy to hear that it worked properly!!

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the link you cited when describing the environment setup, it is necessary to provide the necessary environment information in order to ROS work properly by `source` the appropriate script:

```sh
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
```

You can include it directly in your bash profile as suggested in the documentation.

In addition, you can do it as well in your `BashOperator` before trying performing the `rosbag` command invocation:

```py
rosbag_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='rosbag',
    bash_command='source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash && rosbag ...',
    # ...
)
```

Comment: I just added source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash to my bash file and it works fine! Thanks